# Input a string stored in array using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I'm trying to input a name to store in the array using for loop. It always jump to enter grade instead of entering a name first. I can't upload a picture but the result would be like this

```
 //Enter number of student: 2
//Enter name of student 1:  Enter grade: 78
//Enter name of student 2:  Enter grade:   


    import java.util.*;

    public class one{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n;
    double sum = 0, ave;

    System.out.print(" Enter number of student: ");
    n = keyboard.nextInt();
   //declare arrays
    String[] student = new String[n+1];
    double[] grade = new double[n+1];

   //inputs
    for(int i=1; i<student.length; i++)
    {
    System.out.print(" Enter name of student " + i + ": ");
    student[i] = keyboard.nextLine(); //input a string
    System.out.print(" Enter grade: ");
    grade[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

  //compute for average
    System.out.println();
   for(int i=1; i<grade.length; i++)
   {
       System.out.println("    " + student[i] + "   " + grade[i]);
       sum = sum + grade[i];
   }
       ave = sum/n;
       System.out.println("\n Average: " + ave);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems that I'm not allowed to post a photo. Instead I edited the description above and add what the output would be like. Please help me.

Comment: @christian read the duplicate question and answers

Comment: @FastSnail thank you so much . my program is now working.

Comment: @christian good luck ..